# Can Pandas use a list for groupby?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

rng = np.random.RandomState(0)
df = pd.DataFrame({'key':['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C'],
                   'data1': range(6),
                   'data2': rng.randint(0, 10, 6)}, 
                  columns=['key', 'data1', 'data2'])
df

   key data1 data2
0   A   0   5
1   B   1   0
2   C   2   3
3   A   3   3
4   B   4   7
5   C   5   9


L = [0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0]
print(df.groupby(L).sum())
```

The output is:

```
  data1 data2
0   7   17
1   4   3
2   4   7
```

I need a clear explanation, please?! What are 0s, 1s and 2 in the `L`? Are they `key` column of the `df`? or are they index label of `df`? And how groupby grouped based on `L`?

Comment: L is a list of values which is used to group the dataframe. If you replace all 0's with a's & 1's with b's & 2 with c's, you will get the exact same result. They need not be a,b,c, they can be r, p , l or whatever as well. The length of L however should be same as the length of the dataframe, if not, it will not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the L is a list of integers in your example. As you groupby L you simply saying: Look at this list of integers and group my df based on those unique integers.

I think visualizing it will make sense (**note that the df doesn't have column L - I just added it for visualization**) :

[image]

groupby L means - take the unique values (in this case 0,1 and 2) and do sum for data1 and data2. So the result for data1 when L=0 would be for data1: 0+2+5=7 (etc)

[image]

and the end result would be:

```
df.groupby(L).sum()
```

​

```
    data1   data2
0   7       17
1   4       3
2   4       7
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It has been two days and I couldn't figure it out. I got it now.

Comment: @Parisa Zaeri this is why Stackoverflow is here. Glad I could help

Answer (score 2):

You can use a list to group observations in your `dataframe`. For instance, say you have the heights of a few people:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'names':['John', 'Mark', 'Fred', 'Julia', 'Mary'],
                   'height':[180, 180, 180, 160, 160]})

print(df)
```

```
   names  height
0   John     180
1   Mark     180
2   Fred     180
3  Julia     160
4   Mary     160
```

And elsewhere, you received their assigned groups:

```
sex = ['man', 'man', 'man', 'woman', 'woman']
```

You won't need to concatenate a new column to your `dataframe` just to group them. You can use the list to do the work:

```
df.groupby(sex).mean()
```

```
       height
man       180
woman     160
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see here how it's working:

```
In [6006]: df.groupby(L).agg(list)                                                                                                                                                             
Out[6006]: 
         key      data1      data2
0  [A, C, C]  [0, 2, 5]  [5, 3, 9]
1     [B, A]     [1, 3]     [0, 3]
2        [B]        [4]        [7]
```

```
In [6002]: list(df.groupby(L))                                                                                                                                                                 
Out[6002]: 
[(0,   key  data1  data2
  0   A      0      5
  2   C      2      3
  5   C      5      9), 
(1,   key  data1  data2
  1   B      1      0
  3   A      3      3), 
(2,   key  data1  data2
  4   B      4      7)]
```

In L, it groups the The 0, key, which is ACC, index 0,2m5 the 1 key is BA, index 1,3, and the two key is B, index 4

This is due to the alignment of the L key:

```
df['L'] = L

  key  data1  data2  L
0   A      0      5  0
1   B      1      0  1
2   C      2      3  0
3   A      3      3  1
4   B      4      7  2
5   C      5      9  0
```

I hope this makes sense